# How can I overload = and [] operators at the same time in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

Here I want to get rid of insert function by overloading [] and = operators.
By overloading [] operator, I have successfully returned the address of the required location where I want to insert the value.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define const maxSize = 30;

class ARRAY
{
private:
    int *ar;
    int end;
public:
    ARRAY()
    {
        ar = new int[40];
        end = -1;
    }

    void insert(int value)
    {
        end += 1;
        ar[end] = value;
    }

    void insert(int value, int index)
    {
        if (index<30 && index >-1)
        {
            int tempEnd = end;
            for (int i = end; i >= index; --i)
            {
                ar[tempEnd + 1] = ar[tempEnd];
                tempEnd -= 1;
            }
            end += 1;
            ar[index] = value;

        }
        else
            cout << "\nOVERFLOW";
    }

    void remove(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index <= end)
        {
            for (int i = index; i < end; ++i){

                ar[i] = ar[i + 1];
            }
            end -= 1;
            //do something
        }
        else
            cout << "\nNothing gonna happens";
    }

    void display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <=end; ++i)
            cout << "\n" << ar[i];
    }

    int* operator[](int at)
    {
        if (at < 40){
            end++;
            return (&ar[at]);

        }
    }

    //Here I want to do = operator overloading, How can I do this?
};

int main()
{
    ARRAY arr;
    arr.insert(1);
    arr.insert(2);
    arr.insert(3);
    arr.insert(4);
    arr.insert(5);
    arr[5] = 10;
    arr.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Defining `operator =` on the class will provide an assignment operator for that *class* not something a method of that class returns. So, no. It's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to overlaod the assignment operator '=' for your purpose. Only overload the access operator '[]'.
That should look something like this:

```
returntype& operator [](int indexvariable);
```

That is going to give you a reference to an instance of returntype and therefore you wont need to overload the assignment operator of your returntype in your case.

Then you can write:

```
arr[5] = 23;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desirable behavior by changing the return type of your `operator[]`:

```
int& operator[](int at)
```

In your original code it returns pointer to the array element, which, even if changed, does not do anything with the value stored in the array. With your original code, you could write something like this to change the element's value:

```
*(arr[5]) = 10;
```

which looks unobvious.

If you return reference instead of pointer, you can directly change the value it references to.

Comment: I have already done this before but I want to do this in this  way which I have mentioned above, is it possible ?

Comment: @MuhammadKhurramRaza overloading `operator =` for class `ARRAY` has absolutely *nothing* to do with the error you're currently receiving for `arr[5] = 10;`. An overload of `operator =` for `ARRAY` would be for assigning `ARRAY` objects; not elements held within those objects.

Comment: @MuhammadKhurramRaza If your `operator[]` returns pointer, you always have to dereference it before usage, so, your code will look like `*(arr[5]) = 10`. Actually, having `operator[]` returning something other than reference is just misleading, consider renaming this operator to some member function, like `int* getElementPointer(int at)`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve pretty much any desirable behavior with some trickery.
In your case, if you want some specific action for `operator=` (e.g. check bounds & insert a new element), you can introduce a helper class, that will hold a reference to an array and an index, and then overload the `operator=` for that class:

```
class ArrayIndex
{
  ARRAY& array;
  int index;
public:
  ArrayIndex(ARRAY& a, int i) : array(a), index(i) {}
  void operator=(int value)
   { array.insert(value,index); }
};
```

And of course you tweak your `ARRAY`'s `operator[]` to return the `ArrayIndex` object.

If you don't want the insertion or any unusual actions, and only want to access the elements, then `operator[]` returning the reference (`int&`) will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment OP left on [akexeykuzmin0's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41893069/5470596), I suggest to alter your `operator[]` to return a handler to your element.

```
#include <iostream>
struct ARRAY
{
    struct Handler
    {
        int* _ptr;
        Handler(int* ptr) : _ptr(ptr) {}
        int& operator*() { return *_ptr; }
        operator int*() { return _ptr; }
        int& operator=(int const& value) { *_ptr = value; return **this; }
    };

    int _value;
    ARRAY(int n) : _value(n) {}
    Handler operator[](size_t) { return Handler(&_value); }
};

int main() {
    ARRAY arr(42);
    std::cout
        << std::hex << &arr._value << "\n"
        << std::dec << arr._value << "\n"
        << *arr[0] << "\n\n";

    arr[0] = 137;
    std::cout
        << std::hex << &arr._value << "\n"
        << std::dec << arr._value << "\n"
        << *arr[0] << "\n\n";

    int* pvalue = arr[0];
    *pvalue = 0;
    std::cout
        << std::hex << &arr._value << "\n"
        << std::dec << arr._value << "\n"
        << *arr[0] << "\n\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -Werror main.cpp && ./a.out
0x7ffd682844f0
42
42

0x7ffd682844f0
137
137

0x7ffd682844f0
0
0
```

[Live demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cee6b8b71983be24)

This handler can be implicitly converted to a `int*` and you *can* overload the `operator=` on it.